# OOP - Mutual and Circular dependency bad design

Tags: oop, dependencies

Globally we all agree when saying that circular ( or mutual ) dependency are bad OOP design.

So, here is a case I'm often facing in which I am forced to deal with services mutual dependency.

Imagine a UserManager, that handle registration and removal of a user.
A ForumManager, that handle post sending, and post removal.

ForumManager depends on UserManager because when sending a post the service must get some infos from UserManager. 
The thing that can appear bad design will be UserManager depending on ForumManager, because if we imagine our codebase to be layered, UserManager is the base layer on which we build forums ( with ForumManager ).

But here is the catch, when removing a user, UserManager must tell ForumManager to remove all user posts, so ... UserManager now depends on ForumManager and we got a circular / mutual dependency.

I often solve this by injecting the services container in UserManager and I'm telling myself that UserManager doesn't really depends on ForumManager, it kinds of lazy loads it with services container, but in facts it is really a dependency as the UserManager would not works correctly if posts were not removed. So, we cannot correctly use UserManager without ForumManager and vice versa, it is a circular / mutual dependency ... and it seems to be bad design.

Your point on this ?

Thank you.

EDIT:
I am thinking of solving that by using events. UserManager isn't supposed to know that the removal of a user should engender removal of posts, because it don't know that forums exists. So, instead, the idea is to only dispatch a "UserRemovalEvent" that ForumManager listen to, and itself decides that corresponds to removing posts from this user.
This approach is quite nice, no ?

Answer (score 0):

What might help is to use a third 'Manager', e.g. post manager.

The ForumManager depends on UserManager like normal.  However, the posts itself are stored in PostManager.

When removing a user, the UserManager tells the PostManager to remove the posts.

Abstract: instead of having a circular dependency, you take out a part that causes it, and create a new (smaller) 'Manager' to remove the circular dependency.

Comment: hmm, it works but we don't longer respect the layers when doing that ?

Comment: I think you still can use layers, UserManager/ForumManager will be in the same layer though, and PostManager will be lower.
I don't know about the events, if events are handled by higher layers, you will have the same problems I guess.